# View onenote folder and files

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-onenote

I am trying to get existing files in one note and I keep getting a generic error that doesn't have any details , `Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.`

```
        var clientId = "client";
        var tenantId = "tenant";
        var clientSecret = "secret";
        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
        var sharedDriveItems = await graphClient.Drives.GetAsync(); //fails on this
```

I've set up a key and confirmed the values on portal.azure.com and I've set up the read permissions for microsoft graph. Is there anyway to get a more detailed error message or something to double check to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get detailed error messages:

```
try
{
    var sharedDriveItems = await graphClient.Drives.GetAsync(); //fails on this
}
catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
}
```